# How can I relax PHP's open_basedir restriction?

Tags: php, security, apache

[open_basedir](http://www.php.net/features.safe-mode) limits the files that can be opened by PHP within a directory-tree.

I am storing several class libraries and configuration files outside of my web root directory.  This way the web server does not make them publicly accessible.  However when I try to include them from my application I get an open_basedir restriction error like this:

> Warning: realpath()
>   [function.realpath]: open_basedir
>   restriction in effect.
>   File(/var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/zend/application)
>   is not within the allowed path(s):
>   (/var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/httpdocs:/tmp)
>   in
>   /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/httpdocs/index.php
>   on line 5

My web root is here:

```
/var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/httpdocs
```

My libraries and configuration directory are here:

```
/var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/zend
```

What would be the best workaround to relax the open_basedir restriction so that the the directory tree under the domain folder becomes available to my application?  I have a number of domains that I want to do this with, and I'm also obviously wary of creating security vulnerabilities.

Note: I am using CentOS, Apache, Plesk, and I have root ssh access to the server. And though this doesn't apply to Zend Framework directly, I am using it in this instance.  So here is the inclusion from Zend's bootstrap:

```
define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../zend/application/'));
set_include_path(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../zend/library' . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can also do this easily on a per-directory basis using the Apache (assuming this is your web server) configuration file (e.g. httpd.conf)

```
<Directory /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/httpdocs>
php_admin_value open_basedir "/var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/httpdocs:/var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/zend"
</Directory>
```

you can also completely remove the restriction with

```
<Directory /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/httpdocs>
php_admin_value open_basedir none
</Directory>
```

Comment: If the op is running plesk he'll need to be slightly more special than that: http://www.toosweettobesour.com/2008/02/02/plesk-open_basedir-workaround/

Comment: tom: Wouldn't removing the restriction entirely create a security vulnerability?
dcousineau: thanks!

Comment: Brian: You would be only removing the restriction for php files being run from /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/httpdocs , but yes the first option is better

Comment: php_admin_value open_basedir none solved my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

add the paths you need to access to (/var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/zend) to your open_basedir directive (you can specify several paths using the path separator ':' or ';' in windows)

note that the values in the open_basedir are prefixes, which means that anything under the /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/zend will be accessible

Answer (score 1):

In Parallels Plesk Panel (e.g. 1and1) you can do it in the PHP panel settings:

[image]

here:

[image]

Comment: Thx Igor, but why "*ex: 1and1*"? Do they not allow PHP overrides?

Comment: Yes, but just through their panel. Maybe the confusion is because the word `ex`, I changed by e.g.