# Drupal / ImageMagick Error: open_basedir restriction in effect

Tags: drupal, imagemagick, open-basedir

I'm trying to use the ImageMagick toolkit in Drupal, but keep getting this error:

```
warning: file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect. 
File(/usr/bin/convert) is not within the allowed path(s): 
(/var/www/vhosts/dev.mysite.com/dev2.mysite.com/drupal/:/tmp/) in 
/var/www/vhosts/dev.mysite.com/dev2.mysite.com/drupal-6.22/includes/image.imagemagick.inc 
on line 55.
No file /usr/bin/convert could be found. PHP's open_basedir security restriction 
is set to /var/www/vhosts/dev.mysite.com/dev2.mysite.com/drupal/:/tmp/, which 
may be interfering with the attempts to locate ImageMagick.
```

I've read many posts on Drupal forums and "around", and have tried various suggested solutions (setting my directory in Drupal to /sites/default/files/tmp, etc.), but so far, nothing has worked.  At this point, since I  do have access to php.ini, I was thinking I could edit it, but am wondering if editing it is the right way to go?   I'm concerned whether adding /usr/bin/convert to the allowed paths in php.ini is a security issue or if there's another way to get it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Created vhost.conf inside /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/conf and restarted apache

```
<Directory /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/httpdocs>
php_admin_value open_basedir none
</Directory>
```

[How can I relax PHP's open_basedir restriction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223800/how-can-i-relax-phps-open-basedir-restriction)

Also, ran as root:

```
yum install ImageMagick
yum install ImageMagick-devel
yum install php-pear
pecl install imagick
```

http://24x7servermanagement.com/blog/?p=754

However, the last step I ran into issues with. It was solved when I called the server company, and I think they ran

```
yum install kernel-devel kernel-headers
```