# scanning /home/ with opendir()

Tags: php, apache, file-permissions

Is it possible to scan /home/ directory with opendir and scandir. When i try to exec script it says permission denied what should i do?

```
<?php

$dir = '/home/';
$dirs = scandir($dir);
?>
<pre>
<?php print_r($dirs); ?>
</pre>
```

Comment: You can, yes, but you need to have permissions on the home directory to do so.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `is_readable('/home/')` to check if you have permission. If not you'd need to make sure the directory has read privileges, probably `0755` (rwxr-xr-x)

Comment: Is there any cons of setting chmod 755 of /home/ on a server with 500+ websites ?

Comment: In my case, `scandir` was performed on `/var/logs/project` and I had to ensure that all the folders i.e. `/var`, `/var/logs` and `/var/logs/project` are all readable and executable for users not in group. I did `chmod 755 /var`, `chmod 755 /var/logs` and `chmod -R 755 /var/logs/project`.

Answer (score 2):

For security, PHP defines a 'basedir', below which you are not allowed to access.  As Aleks G says, there is also the file permissions to consider.

This question talks about how to get around basedir restrictions: [How can I relax PHP's open_basedir restriction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223800/how-can-i-relax-phps-open-basedir-restriction)

Tom Haigh's answer copied to here:

You can also do this easily on a per-directory basis using the Apache (assuming this is your web server) configuration file (e.g. httpd.conf)

```
<Directory /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/httpdocs>
php_admin_value open_basedir "/var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/httpdocs:/var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/zend"
</Directory>
```

you can also completely remove the restriction with

```
<Directory /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/httpdocs>
php_admin_value open_basedir none
</Directory>
```

Comment: I tried it and but still cant access it still permission denied

Comment: Then, as the other answers say, you need to enable read permission for the apache process.  You can `chmod g+rx-w /home` and change the group of the /home folder from root to www-data (or whatever your apache has access to - make a new group if necessary)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a PHP programmer, but I think your problem is that when PHP tries the opendir, it is running with the same user ID as apache has, which may not have permission to read your /home directory.

You could fix that by altering the permissions on /home, or adding the apache userid to whatever group has group ownership of home.

Possibly it is a problem in your Apache configuration file.  Even if the filesystem permissions would permit it, your httpd.conf file may not allow access to /home.  That would usually be the case if all of your HTML files are in /var/www.

The httpd.conf might be set up to allow serving files out of your users' home directories.  In that case the permission would be granted for directories within /home but not for /home itself.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in your question: it's a permission problem.  Most likely, the process under which Apache is running does not have permission to read `/home` directory (or your usernamd, if running in CLI).  Manually do this in a terminal:

```
ls -ld /home
```

and check the attributes.