# PHP shell_exec() not working

Tags: php, centos6, shell-exec

I tend to use one of a programms that i installed on my vps server ,

the script which i made is work perfectly on my localhost , but it doesn't work on vps.

Here what i tried

```
$r = shell_exec('wkhtmltopdf http://monsite.ma/generate/15 /var/www/vhosts/monsite.ma/qr-u15.pdf');
// $r contain a null variable
```

Full path command also not working .

i have centos6.5 with php5.5 installed on my vps too .

and Windows7 with php5.5 on my localhost

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20124327/php-shell-exec-command-is-not-working

Comment: What happens when you run `wkhtmltopdf http://monsite.ma/generate/15 /var/www/vhosts/monsite.ma/qr-u15.pdf` from command line without php?

Comment: Is shell_exec returning NULL ?