# How to execute shell_exec on EC2 Linux

Tags: php, python, amazon-ec2, shell-exec

I am running an API on a EC2 Linux instance. I try to to execute a Python script from a PHP file. The path to the PHP file is `/var/www/html/droptop/api/event/test.php`. The path to the Python script is `/var/www/html/droptop/blacklist/profanity.py`. The Python script recieves two strings and checks whether one of these two strings contain objectionable content via **Profanity Check**. Then it returns **0** if no objectionable content was found, otherwise it returns **1**. However, `shell_exec`always seems to return `NULL`. **Profanity Check** needs Python 3 to work properly.

When executed on command line, the PHP file and Python script perfectly work fine together.

I assume it has something to do with the user's permissions. `apache` and not `www-data` user is executing the files. However, I also changed the `sudoers` file according to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36967642/python-script-through-php-on-amazon-ec2). I included following lines:

```
apache ALL=NOPASSWD:/var/www/html/droptop/blacklist/profanity.py
apache ALL=NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/python3.6
```

I also checked if `apache` is part of `groups` which it is.

I also tried other functions like `exec()`, `system()` or `passthru()`.

Still it always returns `NULL`.

**test.php**

```
$command = escapeshellcmd('python3 /var/www/html/droptop/blacklist/profanity.py Some BadWord');
$output = shell_exec($command);

if($output == 0) {
  echo json_encode(array("message" => "No Badword found."));
}
```

**profanity.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python36

from profanity_check import predict, predict_prob
import sys

# get title
title = sys.argv[1]
pred_title = predict([title])
pred_details = 0

if(len(sys.argv) == 3):
    details = sys.argv[2]
    pred_details = predict([details])

if((pred_title == 0) and (pred_details == 0)):
    print(0)
else:
    print(1)
```

What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove these `sudoers` entries, they shouldn't be necessary in your case and it's a security risk.

I would also recommend to not relay on the output and use the exit status instead:

**test.php**

```
<?php
$command = escapeshellcmd('python3 /var/www/html/droptop/blacklist/profanity.py Some BadWord');
exec($command, $output, $return_var);

//echo $output;

if(!$return_var) {
  echo json_encode(array("message" => "No Badword found."));
}
?>
```

**profanity.py**

```
import sys

from profanity_check import predict


def profanity(words):
    return predict(words)

def main():
    words = sys.argv[1:]
    ret = profanity(words)
    sys.exit(any(ret))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Now, back to your original issue, the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) says

> This function can return NULL both when an error occurs or the program
>   produces no output.

You can un-comment the `//echo $output;` line and assuming you're using Apache web server running as `apache` user you can try to run the command below, hopefully this will give you some clue:

```
$ runuser -l apache -s /bin/bash -c "php -f /var/www/html/droptop/api/event/test.php; echo"
{"message":"No Badword found."}
```

Possible issues:

- your python installation is not in the `$PATH` for `apache` user
- `profanity_check` module is not installed globally

Answer (score 0):

Try check the error logs
The server access point to the web is controlled by the web server 
It could be that there are permission issue to the file you want to write. 
For example I was trying to write to a file owned by "user" but apache "www-data" has no permission
check the error logs inside:

**/var/log/apache2**

They may be instructive into seeing what is the real problem.