# Calling a python script from PHP, facing issue related to writing, reading of file when open on browser

Tags: php, python, python-3.x, python-2.7, subprocess

I have a python script, which I am calling from the php file.

My output is coming as expected, when run as python test.py

But when I am trying to run the php file through the browser, I am not getting the output.

However, on commenting the following lines, I am able to get some results. But I want these lines to run.

```
with open(filen,'w') as f:
                     f.write(str("write date"))
```

I am not sure, what's happening. Can anyone explain what difference its making when php reaches these lines.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the question is not clear. I'm guessing you want to execute a python script from php. Your python script does not output anything but write to a file.

executing a python file from php

```
<?php
print shell_exec("python test.py");
?>
```

this question may help you if the code above doesn't work: [php shell_exec() command is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20124327/php-shell-exec-command-is-not-working)

please edit your question for a more accurate response.