# Trying to run command line jq from php

Tags: php, json, linux, curl, jq

I have been trying to run this PHP script. There is no output whatsoever and I cannot seem to understand the reason.

```
<?php

echo "Example DOI Query <be>";

$doi = someDOIvalue;

echo 'DOI: '.$doi.'<br>';

$query = 'curl -LH "Accept: application/json" http://doi.org/';

$cmd = $query.$doi." | jq '.title'";

echo $cmd;

$title = shell_exec($cmd);

echo 'Title:<br>'.$title;

?>
```

However, when I try to use the same command on my LINUX command line (as below), it works perfectly fine.

```
curl -LH "Accept: application/json" http://doi.org/10.1016/someDOIvalue | jq '.title'
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I would check your webserver logs, PHP probably doesn't have permission to run an exec or something like that. Is this CentOS?

Comment: Also try calling jq from its absolute path like `/usr/bin/jq`.

Comment: No, using Debian Linux.

Comment: tried the absolute path too. It didn't work for me!

Comment: Have you had a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20124327/php-shell-exec-command-is-not-working to see if anything helps.

Comment: @Nigel thanks! It worked. Turns out I need to give full path names for both `jq` and `curl`

Answer (score -2):

there are a lot of reasons for this issue try to check

the group and the permission also use the full path of the command

I hope it's help full