Running shell command on Ubuntu via PHP
I have a simple script that has this command in it:
shell_exec("source ~/.bashrc");

The output is:
sh: 1: source: not found

This happens with all commands. For example:
shell_exec("pm2 restrat 3");

returns the same error:
sh: 1: pm2: not found

As I am using new server which "managed" I guess I can fix that by setting up something on it ? Not sure what cause this. Red several articles around but can't seem to understand what is the case.

"shell_exec might not know what directory to look in for your executable's location directory" - https://stackoverflow.com/a/55940724/6055465 . Have you tried an absolute path to pm2? As for source not being found.. That is a built-in command, so the shell that is being executed doesn't have it. Maybe put your scripts into a .sh file and then execute /usr/bin/bash myscript.sh?

If you're running that php file through the web, then the home directory of the user that runs the webserver wouldn't exist since it should be a daemon-only user, so ~/.bashrc wouldn't exist.

source is a bash extension. All the functions that execute shell commands use sh, and the correct command is ., e.g. shell_exec(". ~/.bashrc");

Assuming you're running PHP FPM and executing this from the web, PHP itself runs as a particular user. By default, this is typically www-data, which is a non-interactive user. That means that it won't have traditional shell access out of the box. Ideally, you want to create a new pool configuration with a more appropriate user if you want PHP to be able to execute shell commands from the web.

Thank you all. Will check all suggestions now.

Actually I am executing it throug the terminal. Want to set it as CRON job.

If you're executing such a simple command via CLI, why are you even using PHP?

@maiorano84 Presumably it's not the only thing in the script.

Note that each call to shell_exec() starts a new shell, so changes loaded from .bashrc will not persist between them. You need to execute something like . ~/.bashrc; pm2 restart 3 in a single call.

I would expect a command like shell_exec to spawn /bin/sh, so if you want anything bash-specific, launch bash specifically: bash -c '. ~/.bashrc; pm2 restart 3', or launch bash with the right options to read it automatically: bash -lic 'pm2 restart 3'

If you need to source your .bashrc, run multiple commands or just need more control over the script environment in general, it might make more sense to put everything in a single script file and execute that. And make sure to provide the full path to shell_exec().
