# Behaviour of glob function in php is different with open_basedir

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I migrate from sugar 5.2 to sugar crm 6.2 and i'm using open_basedir and it doesn't work ...

I detected the problem in the code. It's the function glob which returns false (with open_basedir) instead of an blank array (with open basedir disactivated)

The file with the problem is *modules/ModuleBuilder/parsers/views/History.php* line 72.

```
foreach (glob($this->getFileByTimestamp('*')) as $filename)
        {
             if(preg_match('/(\d+)$/', $filename, $match)) {
                $this->_list [] = $match[1];
             }
        }
```

(if glob return null, there is an error)

When I look for the documentation of glob https://www.php.net/glob, there is a flag *GLOB_ERR* : *Stop on read errors (like unreadable directories), by default errors are ignored.*

But it doesn't change, the result is false and I've no error.

The configuration of open base dir allow the application path, /tmp and /usr/share

Does someone know how to resolve that problem without modify the code (or how to add an upgrade safe code)

**Edit**

The path looked by the glob function is located within the path of the open basedir, it's in the sugarcrm directory. The glob function only return false when there is no matching file (behaviour without open base dir for the same case : blank array). When there are files in both case it will return a populated array.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I relax PHP's open_basedir restriction?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/223800/how-can-i-relax-phps-open-basedir-restriction)

Comment: no it isn't I add some information ..

Comment: Well, regardless, the linked answer will tell you how to solve your question. If `open_basedir` restrictions prevent access to a directory, neither `glob` nor any other function will be able to access that directory. **You'll have to change your `open_basedir` settings.**

Comment: the configuration of open_basedir permit the listing of the matching directory, for example, this file will call glob many times and in will return false only in the case of open_basedir is setted. (in other case it will work the same)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read about this bug https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=47358

Possible solution is

```
$temp = glob($this->getFileByTimestamp('*'));
if (is_array($temp))
foreach ($temp as $filename)
        {
             if(preg_match('/(\d+)$/', $filename, $match)) {
                $this->_list [] = $match[1];
             }
        }
```

Comment: the problem is solved in sugarcrm 6.4 https://github.com/sugarcrm/sugarcrm_dev/blob/master/modules/ModuleBuilder/parsers/views/History.php