# How to upload a file to a folder outside web root

Tags: php, file-upload, wamp

I've looked around here for similar question but couldn't find any that solved my problem.
I want to upload a file to a folder just above the web root (www folder). I'm running wamp on windows. Please how do I achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: Like any other upload... then just move the file to the desired location. [PHP manual on POST uploads](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)

Comment: reference this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/223800/how-can-i-relax-phps-open-basedir-restriction

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default files will be uploaded well above the web root for security and you have to move them to wherever you want. Take a look at [move_uploaded_file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php).

Have a look at `print_r($_FILES)` and it will show you the location of each file you have uploaded.

Comment: I don't want to reconfigure my apache server because I do not have that privilege on my hosting server, I've used move_uploaded_file() to move file into my web root, but now I want them to move to a name directory just above the web root.

Comment: you can move it to whatever folder you need, just change the second parameter in move_uploaded_file()

Comment: Yes I know I can, I tried this $upload_folder = "../../matrials/"; because the upload script is in a file that is inside a folder inside the document root (mywebsitefolder/user/the-upload-script.php). the folder "materials" is just above my web root, i.e materials/www/ I don't know what else to try. Thanks for your time

Comment: Give it a full path like: `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/www/'` - you should use a relative path

Comment: Just to clear something up, my last comment should say "shouldn't" ;)

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to what I use for images uploaded via forms. This is presuming the input field has a name of 'image'.

```
function getExtension($str) {
    $i = strrpos($str,".");
    if (!$i) { return ""; }
    $l = strlen($str) - $i;
    $ext = substr($str,$i+1,$l);
    return strtolower($ext);
}    

// Get the extension of the uploaded file
$ext = getExtension($_FILES['image']['name']);

// Give the file a new name (if you need) and append the extension.
$img_name = time().$ext;

// Set destination for upload
$new_image = "./images/uploaded/" . $img_name;

// Copy the file to the new location
$copied = copy($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $new_image);
```

You can use this for any file uploaded, as the previous answer stated, doing a `var_dump($_FILES)` will show you everything you need to know about your uploaded file before you do anything with it.