# how to access file from outside root directory in php

Tags: php, file

I have a code to download zip files:

```
$dl_path = './';  
$filename = 'favi.zip';  
$file = $dl_path.$filename; 
if (file_exists($file))  {
  header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
  header('Content-Type: application/zips');     
  header("Pragma: public");     
  header("Expires: 0");     
  header("Cache-Control:must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"); 
  header("Content-Type:application/force-download");    
  header("Content-Type:application/download");  
  header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=$filename ");     
  header("Content-Transfer-Encoding:binary ");
  header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
  ob_clean();
  flush();
  readfile($file);
  exit;
}
```

there is root directory `/public_html`, the script is executing in root directory.

there is zip file in `/` directory.

i am trying to use the `$dl_path` as `/` but it is not working.

Please help.

Comment: 1. format your code correctly; 2. use ../ as path to move below public_html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$dl_path = __DIR__.'/..'; // parent folder of this script
$filename = 'favi.zip';
$file = $dl_path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filename;

// Does the file exist?
if(!is_file($file)){
    header("{$_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']} 404 Not Found");
    header("Status: 404 Not Found");
    echo 'File not found!';
    die;
}

// Is it readable?
if(!is_readable($file)){
    header("{$_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']} 403 Forbidden");
    header("Status: 403 Forbidden");
    echo 'File not accessible!';
    die;
}

// We are good to go!
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control:must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Type: application/download");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename={$filename}");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary ");
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
while(ob_get_level()) ob_end_clean();
flush();
readfile($file);
die;
```

^ **try this code**. See if it works. If it doesn't:

- If it `404`'s means the file is not found.
- If it `403`'s it means you can't access it *(permissions issue)*.

Comment: Yes, it's working, Thanking You. And A small thing, downloaded file is saved as 'favi.zip' instead of favi.zip. how to change that.

Comment: Fixed the `header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename={$filename}");` to work properly now.

Answer (score 0):

First of all check if your script is running under the correct directory by echoing `dirname(__FILE__)`.

If it is running under `public_html` then you can change the code like this:

```
$dl = dirname(__FILE__). '/../';
```

But beware of security issue!

1. Check if you have read/write permission on the file *and* directory
2. Check the `open_basedir` restriction in `php.ini` (see [How can I relax PHP's open_basedir restriction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223800/how-can-i-relax-phps-open-basedir-restriction))

Hope this helps