# Disable direct downloads

Tags: php, apache, file, download

I'm working on a high security system which is being developed in PHP. There are some files that are uploaded by the user and get uploaded to a directory. How can I make it so that you can't just go to the url of the file and it downloads? However I still need to be able to download the file from an administration section of the site.

Thanks

Comment: make the directory outside the web route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this, one is to hite the directory of uploaded files by .htaccess file, which contains simply:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
```

Afterwards, when you want to dwonlaod the file (assuming that you have the file paths saved somewhere in a database or you could alternativelly pass them in some form in a GEt parameter), you can download them using a code similar to this (and example based on the PHP documentation):

```
// check user credentials
check_if_logged_in();

// get path to file
$file = get_your_file_path();

if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Placed the files outside of the web directory. Then used this to download: [how to access file from outside root directory in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17896429/how-to-access-file-from-outside-root-directory-in-php)