# PHP download file from /var folder without relative paths

Tags: php

I want to download a file from a folder above web root. Let's say I want to get this file:

```
/var/pdfs/test.pdf
```

My code is:

```
$name = "test.pdf";
$url = "/var/pdfs/" . $name;
if (file_exists($url)) {
    header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename='" . basename($url) . "'");
    readfile($url);
} else {
    echo "Not found: $url";
}
```

The problem is that I always get the `Not found: $url` echo.

My file has read permissions:

```
thecrafter@vps136166:/var/pdfs$ ls -la
total 6484
drwxr--r--  2 thecrafter root          4096 Jul  7 00:19 .
drwxr-xr-x 13 root       root          4096 Jul  7 00:16 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 thecrafter thecrafter 6629018 Jul  7 00:18 test.pdf
```

and directory too:

```
thecrafter@vps136166:/var$ ls -la | grep pdfs
drwxr--r--  2 thecrafter root  4096 Jul  7 00:19 pdfs
```

Do I miss something? Where is the problem?

**EDIT 1**

Krzysztof Duszczyk noted that the problem is solved if I give execute rights to `pdfs` directory. Indeed I gave it `755` and it's working. Any ideas why that happens?

Comment: Does pdfs folder have read rights?

Comment: IMHO there is the same problem, check it. http://stackoverflow.com/a/17896538/6557808

Comment: @KrzysztofDuszczyk Yes, I edited my question.

Comment: Hmmm adding execute rights to pdfs folder helped when I reproduce the problem. Really don't know why :)

Comment: @KrzysztofDuszczyk Wtf. You're right! It's working. Okay now I'm confused.

Comment: I too wonder why that is. I find very little discussion of this aside from https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/471819-Why-is-Linux-execute-bit-needed-for-PHP-s-file_exists()-function-to-work-properly

Comment: What OS are you using and is SELinux enabled?  I replicated your situation and `file_exists` returns true for a file with permissions of 644 in a directory with permissions of 755.  Under the hood, on Linux, PHP just calls the function [`access()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/access.html) to determine file accessibility, so something in the OS is saying no access to the file unless execute is also set.

Comment: @drew010 I'm running `Debian 8.5` and no, I don't have SELinux.

Comment: ubuntu 14.04 here. When permissions are 644 for file and 755 for folder it works the problem is when folder has 644 permissions.

Comment: See bullet point 3 on [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/21252/88823).  Basically the execute but on the directory is what allows the user to enter the directory and list / read contents.

Comment: @drew010 Whoa, interesting! I did not know that thanks! Could you please, write it in an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1):

**The Problem** (not in this case, but I leave it to help others)

If you know that the file actually exists on disk, your `file_exists()` is likely blocked by security measures meant to protect files within `/var/pdfs/` from unauthorized access.  This is from the docs on [file_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php):

> Warning: This function returns FALSE for files inaccessible due to
>   safe mode restrictions. However these files still can be included if
>   they are located in safe_mode_include_dir.

**The solution** (again not in this case, but could help similar symptoms)

You want to add the directory to `safe_mode_include_dir` setting. Find the setting in your `php.ini`, uncomment it, and add the directory:

```
safe_mode_include_dir = /var/pdfs/
```

If this still does not work, you may also need to add the directory to your PHP include path, either by setting the `include_path` in `php.ini`, or at the top of your script, with the line below:

```
$path = '/var/pdfs'
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $path);
```

Note that PHP removed the `safe mode` settings with version `5.4`, so if you have a recent PHP installation, your problem is likely elsewhere.

Comment: I tried adding `ini_set("safe_mode_include_dir", "/var/pdfs/");` on top of my php script. I didn't work so I tried your second solution but it didn't work either.

Comment: I think you misunderstood. I didn't suggest you use `ini_set` to change safe_mode_include_dir. I suggested you make the change in `php.ini` directly.  The 2nd suggestion is in addition to the first (not an alternative), so either way you need to first change `php.ini`.

Comment: Okay. I opened my `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` but there is no `safe_mode_include_dir` option. Not even commented out. Should I just append it?

Comment: First you need to know that it is the `php.ini` actually loaded when PHP starts (lots of discussion on how elsewhere) because there are often several copies of this file. Once you have the right file, yes add the setting if it's not there. You'll then have to restart Apache for the changes to take effect. By the way what version of PHP do you run?

Comment: I'm running `PHP 5.6.20-0+deb8u1`. I appended it to php.ini but still, nothing.

Comment: Apparently, when I add execute rights to pdfs folder (credits to  Krzysztof Duszczyk) it's working. Any ideas why?

Comment: Ok. PHP 5.6.20 doesn't use `safe mode` anymore (removed since 5.4). You can undo your edit. Something else may be going on.