# How to change Codeigniter safe mode off?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to use the backquotes to execute a system command, but it says the following message:

```
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when safe_mode is enabled or an open_basedir is set
```

So.. I guess I need to turn off safe mode. I have no idea how to do this.

Can anyone walk me through? phpinfo() says that my "safe_mode" directive is off for Master Value, but is on for Local Value.

I guess there's a switch somewhere I need to set?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'Master Value'` is basically the value inside php.ini. The `'local value'` is the directory you're looking at.

A simple way is to turn off the safe mode only for that specific directory like the following

Add this to the end of `httpd.conf` and make sure you restart your apache server.

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
php_admin_flag safe_mode off
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue mostly caused by enabled open_basedir php setting, not safe_mode(safe mode setting removed since php5.4 [http://php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223800/how-can-i-relax-phps-open-basedir-restriction), but this issue still appears after that). To rid off this message do one of the following.

1. If you have access to php.ini file, search open_basedir option and uncomment it(like that ;open_basedir=/home/sites/site81/:/tmp/:/) or add this php_admin_value open_basedir "/home/sites/site81/:/tmp/:/" to http.conf apache config file
2. If you use shared hosting, contact to server admins to fix only for host.
   If you use plesk read 3rd answer [How can I relax PHP's open_basedir restriction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223800/how-can-i-relax-phps-open-basedir-restriction)