# How to upload a file into another server in slim3 php

Tags: php, slim

I am using silm3 as my REST API framework and followed [this](https://akrabat.com/psr-7-file-uploads-in-slim-3/) to write my file upload script from API.

I am currently running my web app in a.xyz.com and my REST API is in b.xyz.com . Now I want to upload a picture into a.xyz.com/uploaded/ from b.xyz.com/upload.

```
$newfile->moveTo("/path/to/$uploadFileName");
```

is used to save the file in current subdomain. But I failed to upload it into another subdomain.

I search in the web, but didn't find any clue how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After moving the file on b.xyz.com in the correct position, do the following:

```
// Server B

// Move file to correct position on B
$newfile->moveTo("/path/to/$uploadFileName");

// Send file to A
$request = curl_init('a.xyz.com/upload');
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, [
  'file' => new CURLFile("/path/to/$uploadFileName")
]);
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
echo curl_exec($request);
curl_close($request);
```

a.xyz.com should then accept the file and proceed to storing it. If using Slim, in the same way as b.xyz.com does

```
...
$newfile->moveTo("/path/to/$uploadFileName");
```

or using PHP's core functions

```
// Server A
if ( !empty($_FILES["file"]) && !empty($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]) ) {
  // Move file to correct position on A
  $uploadFileName = basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "/path/to/$uploadFileName");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I think you missed a point. I will upload my file into ('http://b.xyz.com/upload'); first. Then I have to upload it to a.xyz.com .

Comment: Well, do the same thing by just inverting endpoints. Post it from B to A, and on A just move the file to the right position.

Comment: I tried by inverting. But it is not working. Do I need to change any permission in my server?

Comment: Check the edited answer, try it and let me know if it works. No need to change anything in your server's config.

Comment: Here is my code.
http://pastebin.com/D01P4JZC

File is uploading in the current subdomain. But it is not uploading in other subdomain.

Comment: Did you capture the file on the other server?

Comment: I capture the file in b.xyz.com server. But failed to do in a.xyz.com

Comment: Basically what you need to do is upload the file on B, move it to the right place on B, let the server upload it from B to A, move it to the right place on A. If you still have problems, it would be better to get a chat room so we can solve them there.

Answer (score 1):

Normally domains or subdomains are restricted to their own webspace, so you can't read or write other domain's files. The setting is calles open_basedir.

You have to set it in your vhost configuration but there are also other ways, like setting it with a .htacces file if your hoster allows it:
[How can I relax PHP's open_basedir restriction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223800/how-can-i-relax-phps-open-basedir-restriction)