# Wordpress failed update plugins after core upgrade in a new server

Tags: wordpress, plugins, upgrade

I moved a WordPress site from a cpanel server to plesk server. Then, i upgraded manualy the site from 3.5.1 version to 4.8.3. Afterwards i tried to upgrade plugins (fancy box) as well as to intall new plugins (contact form 7).
The issue i have is that i get the following error message "*Update Failed: Download failed. Destination directory for file streaming does not exist or is not writable.*".

### In the server's log file i can see few warning like the following one

*mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning: file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/dentist/domains/dentist.com.gr/public_html/newsite/wp-content/uploads//easy-fancybox.1.6.2-Vlaovu.tmp) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/www/vhosts/ggeorgiou.gr/ggeorgiou.work/:/tmp/) in /var/www/vhosts/ggeorgiou.gr/ggeorgiou.work/wd/dentist.com.gr/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2085, referer: http://www.ggeorgiou.work/wd/dentist.com.gr/wp-admin/plugins.php*

---

Finally, note that in "Settings --> Media" menu in "
Store uploads in this folder" field i have put the following path of  the current server:  "/var/www/vhosts/ggeorgiou.gr/ggeorgiou.work/wd/dentist.com.gr/wp-content/uploads".

Any idea please what is wrong about?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you posted, your exact error message is  `"open_basedir restriction in effect"`. You can read more about how to solve it here [How can I relax PHP's open_basedir restriction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223800/how-can-i-relax-phps-open-basedir-restriction)

Also,

Assuming you have a backup of the previous version, I would start by restoring that.

Secondly, there are many versions between 3.5.1 and 4.8.3. It is advisable to upgrade in increments of one version at a time. It is long but safer.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your response. As far as the upgrade process i did it main version by main version i.e. 3.6 to 3.7 then 3.7 to 3.8 and so on.

Comment: That can work, but in my experience, it's better 3.6.x to 3.6.y  maybe jump one or two. However, usually X.Y yo X.Z is a big jump. In your case, you have probably 10 or so updates along the way.